# How to Sum TR in TABLE

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, sum

```
<table id="tab" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- HERE IS SUM -->
    <tr>
        <td>?</td>
        <td>?</td>
        <td>?</td>
        <td>?</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to add up all the data that is there, which comes out of iteration

so when there are 10 rows of data, then 10 rows will add up

```
for example
A  B  C  D
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
SUM
5  5  5  5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can querySelector all rows, remove the first row and get the last row to populate values, and each row querySelector its column and I have used ES6 map and reduce to accumulate values

```js
const rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'));
const lastRow = rows.splice(rows.length - 1, 1)[0];
// Remove first row
rows.splice(0,1);

const sumArr = rows.reduce((acc,row) => {
   const cols = row.querySelectorAll('td');
   return acc.map((c, i) => c + +cols[i].innerHTML);
}, [0,0,0,0]);

const lastRowCols = lastRow.querySelectorAll('td');

sumArr.forEach((s, i) => {
  lastRowCols[i].innerHTML = s; 
})
```

```html
<table id="tab" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- HERE IS SUM -->
    <tr>
        <td>?</td>
        <td>?</td>
        <td>?</td>
        <td>?</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```